# Select from many tables at once (many to many relations) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I got these tables:

**filminfo:**

- filminfo_id (int)
- filminfo_author (int)
- filminfo_title (varchar)
- filminfo_releaseYear (int)

**Genres:**

- genre_id (int)
- genre_name (varchar)

**filmGenres:**

- filmGenre_id (int)
- filmGenre_filmId (int)
- filmGenre_genreId (int)

**users**

- user_id (int)
- user_firstname (varchar)
- user_lastname (varchar)

**directors:**

- director_id (int)
- director_firstname (varchar)
- director_lastname (varchar)

**filmDirectors:**

- filmDirector_id (int)
- filmDirector_filmId (int)
- filmDirector_directorId (int)

I want to select the following:

- filminfo_id
- filminfo_title
- filminfo_releaseYear
- genre_name (matching filmGenres)
- user_firstname (matching filminfo_author)
- user_lastname  (matching filminfo_author)
- director_firstname (matching filmDirectors)
- director_lastname (matching filmDirectors)

I've been stuck with this the whole day. I love the one who can help me figure this out!

What I've done so far:

```
SELECT
f.filminfo_title,
f.filminfo_releaseYear,
u.user_id,
u.user_firstName,
u.user_lastName,
d.director_firstname,
d.director_lastname,
GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre_name SEPARATOR ', ') genre
FROM (filmGenres fg, filmDirectors fd,filmActors fa) 
INNER JOIN filminfo f ON f.filminfo_id = fg.filmGenre_filmId  
INNER JOIN genres g ON g.genre_id = fg.filmGenre_genreId
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.filminfo_author
INNER JOIN directors d ON d.director_id = fd.filmDirector_directorId
GROUP BY
f.filminfo_title,
f.filminfo_releaseYear
ORDER BY f.filminfo_releaseYear DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Please help!

---

**EDIT:**
I am very close:

```
SELECT
    f.filminfo_title,
    f.filminfo_originalTitle,
    f.filminfo_suggestedAge,
    f.filminfo_runtime,
    f.filminfo_releaseYear,
    f.filminfo_description,
    f.filminfo_youtubeId,
    user_firstname,
    user_lastname,
    fi.filmImage_image,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name SEPARATOR ', ') as genrenames,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(director_firstname, ' ',
                        director_lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') as directors
FROM filmGenres fg
JOIN filminfo f ON f.filminfo_id = fg.filmGenre_filmId
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.filminfo_author
JOIN genres g ON g.genre_id = fg.filmGenre_genreId
JOIN filmDirectors fd ON fd.filmDirector_filmId = f.filminfo_id
JOIN directors d ON d.director_id = fd.filmDirector_directorId
JOIN filmImages fi ON fi.filmImage_id = f.filminfo_id
GROUP BY f.filminfo_title
```

But this returns directors mulitple times (ex: Ridley Scott, Ridley Scott). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working with the code you posted? How is the result not what you expect?

Comment: I've edited my firstpost. The last SQL works, but it duplicates the director name. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: and I've edited my answer, check it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 

    fi.filminfo_id,
    fi.filminfo_title,
    fi.filminfo_releaseYear,
    g.genre_name, -- (matching filmGenres)
    u.user_firstname, -- (matching filminfo_author)
    u.user_lastname, -- (matching filminfo_author)
    d.director_firstname, -- (matching filmDirectors)
    d.director_lastname -- (matching filmDirectors)

From filminfo fi, genres g, filmGenres fg, users u, directors d, filmdirectors fd

Where
        fg.filmGenre_filmId  = fi.filminfo_id
    and fd.filmId=fi.filmInfo_id
    and g.genre_id=fg.filmGenre_genreId
    and u.user_id=fi.filminfo_author
    and d.director_id=filmDirector_directorId
```

This will return multiple rows for the same film if the film has multiple genres, authors or directors. I've not added the order by because it seems inconsequential to answering the question.

**EDIT**

In response to your edited question, add the keyword distinct, so that only distinct rows will be selected. If you still get repeated director names, then that's because your data is such that the film has one director, but multiple authors or genres.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    f.filminfo_title,
    f.filminfo_originalTitle,
    f.filminfo_suggestedAge,
    f.filminfo_runtime,
    f.filminfo_releaseYear,
    f.filminfo_description,
    f.filminfo_youtubeId,
    user_firstname,
    user_lastname,
    fi.filmImage_image,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name SEPARATOR ', ') as genrenames,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(director_firstname, ' ',
                        director_lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') as directors
FROM filmGenres fg
JOIN filminfo f ON f.filminfo_id = fg.filmGenre_filmId
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.filminfo_author
JOIN genres g ON g.genre_id = fg.filmGenre_genreId
JOIN filmDirectors fd ON fd.filmDirector_filmId = f.filminfo_id
JOIN directors d ON d.director_id = fd.filmDirector_directorId
JOIN filmImages fi ON fi.filmImage_id = f.filminfo_id
GROUP BY f.filminfo_title
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that bacause of multiple directors to film relation it does not make sence to output them separately. I concateneted directors as well:

```
SELECT
    filmGenre_filmId,
    filminfo_title,
    filminfo_releaseYear,
    user_firstname,
    user_lastname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name SEPARATOR ', ') as genrenames,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(director_firstname, ' ',
                        director_lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') as directors
FROM filmGenres fg
JOIN filminfo f ON filmGenre_filmId = filminfo_id
JOIN users u ON filminfo_author = user_id
JOIN genres g ON filmGenre_genreId = genre_id
JOIN filmDirectors fd ON filmGenre_filmId = filmDirector_filmId
JOIN directors d ON filmDirector_directorId = director_id 
GROUP BY filmGenre_filmId
```

UPD1:

here is a simplified query which will require some optimizations:

```
SELECT
    filminfo_id,
    filminfo_title,
    filminfo_releaseYear,
    user_firstname,
    user_lastname,
    genrenames,
    directors
FROM filminfo f
JOIN users u ON filminfo_author = user_id
JOIN (
    SELECT
        filmGenre_filmId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name SEPARATOR ', ') as genrenames
    FROM filmGenres
    JOIN genres g ON filmGenre_genreId = genre_id
    GROUP BY filmGenre_filmId
) as g ON filminfo_id = filmGenre_filmId
JOIN (
    SELECT
        filmDirector_filmId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(director_firstname, ' ',
                            director_lastname) SEPARATOR ', ') as directors
    FROM filmDirectors
    JOIN directors d ON filmDirector_directorId = director_id
    GROUP BY filmDirector_filmId
) as d ON filminfo_id = filmDirector_filmId
```

Comment: Close, but it still doesn't work properly. Check my "edit" and you will see why.

Comment: @evenaug, you are right, I used wrong grouping columns. I edited the query and added another one, which should work but may permorm not very good depending on the size of your filminfo table.